# Postgres replication without taking a new base backup of the primary server

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I have configured steaming replication in PostgreSQL. Every time I fail over, I need to take a new base backup to reverse the order of replication. After promoting the standby server, I need to take a base backup to turn the old primary into a new standby server.

How can I turn the old primary into a new standby without taking a base backup?

Answer (score 0):

Simple: by using [`pg_rewind`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrewind.html) instead of `pg_basebackup`. It is an "abbreviated version" of `pg_basebackup`, created specifically for this very purpose.

There are a few requirements for using `pg_rewind`:

- The PostgreSQL cluster has to be created with data checksums (`initdb --data-checksums`), or the parameter `wal_log_hints` has to be turned on. This will increate the amount of WAL written.
- You have to have all WAL on the old primary since the promotion of the old standby. You can use `wal_keep_size` to make sure you have enough old WAL.

The procedure should be like this: first try `pg_rewind`, and only if that fails for some reason, rebuild the standby with `pg_basebackup`.

Comment: After promoting slave has primary, I need to run pg_rewind in old primary server is this right

Comment: Sounds right. I have added a link to the documentation.